# How do I check the uptime of the system with a certain number

Tags: linux, administration

I know how to check uptime of a system with the `top` or `uptime` commands. But what if I need to do this for a system with a specific id?

Comment: What do you mean a system with a specific id?  A remote system?

Comment: @Jesse_b Well...let's say there's a local network and I'm a system administrator. How do I check the uptime for a specific machine? Sorry if I'm saying silly things, I don't quite understand it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   ssh user@server <<'EOF'
   uptime
   EOF
```

Comment: Or simply `ssh user@server uptime`